# How to create a v-if or method that only shows a date bigger than the current date

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I am not sure why my code is not working, because it seems like a fairly simple task.
I am getting a data object from my database that looks like this:

```
    tasks: [
      {
        taskName: null,
        dates: [
          {
            dateOfTask: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

Currently I am outputting the latest task that a user has created

```
    <template v-for="task in tasks">
      <li v-if="task && task.dates && task.dates[0].dateOfTask" class="list-group-item">
        {{ 'Date:' }}
        {{ formatDate(task.dates[task.dates.length - 1].dateOfTask) }}
      </li>
    </template>
```

I have a formatDate method as well.

```
  formatDate(date){
    return moment(date).locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L')
  },
```

What I want is to check if the date of the task is greater or smaller than the current date. If it is smaller, then it should not be shown in the template

What I have tried:

I made a new variable called current, which looks like this:

```
currentDate: moment().locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L')
```

I then tried to make a new condition inside my v-if

```
<li v-if="task && task.dates && task.dates[0].dateOfTask && task.dates[0].dateOfTask > currentDate">
```

This SHOULD in theory only show the data if the dateOfTask is bigger than the currentDate, but even if the dateOfTask is bigger, the data does not show up.
Now I am wondering how I can fix this.

So basically:

If dateOfTask is later than current date: show.

If dateOfTask is earlier than current date: do not show.

Comment: You are currently only checking if the dateOfTask of first array element is greater, is this correct? Side note, you can consider using momentjs `diff()` function

Comment: Yes. I am getting the last element in the array and checking if it is greater.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that you pass a `null` value to `formatDate`, if you initialize a moment with `null` this will return `Invalid date`. And like said by Neelansh is better to use `diff` method.